# Was Prophet Eesa/Jesus (alaihas salaam) the second last prophet before Prophet Muhammad (pbuh)?

Tags: prophets

I know there were more than a hundred-thousand prophets. But was wondering if Hazrat Eesa (alaihas salaam) was among the last prophets mentioned in the Quran?

Answer (score 1):

Talking without references, it is said that there are 124,000 prophets all together from the beginning.

And Allah says,

> **And for every nation is a messenger**. So when their messenger comes, it will be judged between them in justice, and they will not be wronged (Qur'an 10:47)

Since, we've heard only about Prophet Isa(peace be upon him) as the chronological Prophet after Prophet Moosa(peace be upon him) and before Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) does not mean there weren't other prophets in this time gap. Who knows some prophet(peace be upon him) was sent to one of the dense forests of South America, but we do not know or are not notified about. All we know for sure is the fact that Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) was the last and a seal.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 1):

By pure coincidence, just today I was reading the طبقات by Ibn Saʻd. In his chapter on the death of the Prophet he cites a tradition to the effect that every prophet lives half as long as his predecessor. Then he says that Muḥammad lived to be 62 and that his predecessor ʻĪsā b. Maryam lived to be 124. This does imply that ʻĪsā was the second-to-last prophet.

Answer (score -1):

This cant be answered. The Bible calls the Prophet Muhammad the "Holy Spirit", IMO, and off the top of my memory states that the Prophet Jesus is not a king on this earth but has prepared the way him whom I take to be the Prophet Muhammad since he was a leader of a growing kingdom.

So the two Prophets followed each other for that place but this is only one culture out of many.

Interesting question, I hope to learn this in the next world :))

Answer (score -1):

Was Jesus / Jesus (pbuh) the last prophet before Muhammad (pbuh)?
Jesus (pbuh) is a Christian prophet and one of the first prophets and the owner of the law. He was the last prophet before the Prophet of Islam, peace be upon him, and one of the heralds of his advent.

Ref:https://wiki.ahlolbait.com/%D8%AD%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%AA_%D8%B9%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C_%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%87_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85